# Creating new commands inside the bibfile

Tags: macros, biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

Is it possible to create a new command by `\newcommand` or `\def` "**inside**" the .bib-file?

I am using LuaLaTeX and biblatex and organize my bibliography with BibDesk on a mac. I also store information about reprints of paper x in collection y. I add this information in the `Addendum`-field of biblatex by something like

```
\bibstring{reprintin}\intitlepunct\addspace\citeauthor{author:1986}\labelnamepunct\addspace\citetitle{author:1986}\addcomma\space\citeyear{author:1986}
```

etc.

For that I had to define some bibstrings in the preamble fo the .tex-files:

```
\NewBibliographyString{reprintin}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{
    reprintin = {Reprint in},
    }
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{
    reprintin = {Reprint in},
    }
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
    reprintin = {Nachdruck in},
    }
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
    reprintin = {Nachdruck in},
    }
```

I now would like to create a newcommand `\bibreprintin` that allows me to just prompt in the addendum-field `\bibreprintin{author:1986}` instead of entering the above code `bibstring{reprintin} ...`.

Thereby I'd enable myself to change the look of the reprint-information later with "one click" should it become necessary later, and also make it safe that all reprint information for all publications in my bibliorgaphy look the same.

My question now is, if there is any possibility to use commands like `\def`, `\newcommand`, and `\NewBibliographyString` *inside* the .bib-file (for this is only one file) and not just inside every single .tex-file (for these are many different files I am working on).

Comment: As far as I know: no.  But a similar hack could be achieved by adding to your entry/entries: `addendum = {Reprint in \cite{<bibkey>}},`.  Note that what this requires is an extended cycle (`latex, bibtex/biber, latex, bibtex/biber, latex`) since the `cite` command won't be 'noticed' until the second `latex` run.

Comment: You could put your definitions in a `biblatex.cfg`. If such a file is at a place where LaTeX can found it, it will be read after the citation and bibliography styles have been loaded.

Comment: @jon : the downside of `\cite` here is that it is context-sensitive and produces a fullcitation if the reprint is after the present entry and a abbreviated citation if the reprint is in front of the entry. Since - I think - I couldn't find `\shortcite` command, I decided to create my own: `Reprint in: Author. Title, Year`. My question remains for any case in which the user wants to define his own reprint-string.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Sinc this [post (link)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47360/12277) I became careful when it comes to edit package files. Can I edit cfg-files without violating licenses etc.?

Comment: @ClintEastwood -- if the entry has a `shorttitle` field, it will use that in the x-ref; and if you use an author-date system, it will use the last name and date only. Anyway, I think you can combine my idea with bibliography strings put in the .cfg file as suggested.  You will not violate any licence: they are meant as '(user) ConFiGuration' files.  `biblatex.cfg` even has the line '% Put your definitions here.'

Comment: The file is meant for user configuration. But don't edit an existing file in the main folder of biblatex - changes there can easily get lost at updates -, generate a new `bibtex.cfg` and put it in a local texmf tree in a similar location so that it is found first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define (La)TeX commands in the `bib` file via `@preamble` and the `execute` field. The latter is intended for definitions on a per-entry basis.

New bibliography strings should be initialized elsewhere, in one of:

- User configuration file (`biblatex.cfg`)
- Document preamble (`tex` file)
- All relevant localization modules (`lbx` files)
- Style files (`bbx` or `cbx`)

For your case Ulrike's suggestion (the configuration file) seems most appropriate.

Reprints are now best handled with the "related entries" feature in the soon-to-be-released development versions of `biblatex` and `biber`. Here's an example (using only the `tex` file, for simplicity).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewBibliographyString{reprintin}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{reprintin = {Reprint in}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{reprintin = {Nachdruck in}}

\renewcommand*{\relatedpunct}{\intitlepunct}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{orwell,
  title = {Reflections on Gandhi},
  author = {Orwell, George},
  year = {1949},
  journal = {Partisan Review},
  number = {6},
  pages = {85--92},
  related = {gariepy},
  relatedtype = {reprintin}}
@book{gariepy,
  title = {Twentieth-Century Literary Criticism},
  editor = {Gariepy, Jennifer},
  volume = {59},
  year = {1995},
  publisher = {Gale}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{orwell}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Related entry information is formatted by the bibliography macro `related:default` defined in `biblatex.def`. This format can be overridden by defining a bibliography macro `related:<relatedtype>` that takes the related entry key as a single argument. The following will emulate the formatting you currently do in the `addendum` field.

```
\newbibmacro*{related:reprintin}[1]{%
  \entrydata{#1}{%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\labelnamepunct}%
    \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}}}
```

Comment: this is great news. I am glad to learn about the "related entries"-feature. One further question at this point: what is the default format of the output of the related entry? Is it a context-sensitive `\cite` command or is does it always produce the same string? In your example it was `Title. Editor. Publisher, Year`. (No location presumably because you did not enter one.)

Comment: The `location` is printed; refer to the `related:default` bibliography macro defined in `biblatex.def`. `biber` makes data from related entries accessible. Unless you cite a related entry directly, it will have `dataonly=true` set so that it won't be printed in the bibliography. The manual gives further details on the new feature.