# Installing with tlmgr without sudo; to ~/texmf

Tags: texlive

I installed texlive by downloading, extracting and running `sudo ./install-tl`.

I want to use tlmgr for installing a package, eg

```
jdoe@jdoe:~$ tlmgr install moderncv
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2015/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Now, I guess that it it will run without errors if I use sudo, but I have not tried that. I thought it would install to ~/texmf, which should not require sudo, and that is also what I would prefer.

- Isn't it supposed to install to ~/texmf, and thus not require sudo?
- How do I install to ~/texmf?

Comment: You seem to be confusing your managed tree (installed by `install-tl` and in your case owned by root) with the 'personal' tree for stuff you add (`|/texmf`). You can happily install TL without `sudo` in your home directory, but not normally to use `~/texmf` for additional stuff.

Comment: So, to install packages locally, to ~/texmf using tlmgr, I need to install texlive for each user (and not needing any global installation)?

Comment: I previously installed texlive on Ubuntu with apt-get. Texlive then godt installed globally; and packages installed with tlmgr were installed locally in ~/texmf. That's why I expected the above described behaviour.

Comment: perhaps the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution, especially the bit about changing ownership, might be helpful here...

Comment: How many users are on the machine? I tend to install in /opt/texlive letting the texlive folder be owned by me. If it is a multi user system, I might create a special use to maintain it and let that user own the texlive folder in /opt

Comment: Besides, why installing locally, why not globally?

Comment: @daleif: Why installing locally: I want to modify the stylesheets for a certain package. It seems very wrong to me, to modify such files globally.

Comment: @daleif: I installed texlive with `install-tl`, which installs globally to certain predefined folders. If you are able to install to /opt/ does that mean that I am able to install everything in one folder, in my home dir?

Comment: Of course, in general I would not recommend installing tl as root. If you want to locally  modify some package, then that package will never be installed by tlmgr, that is not what it is made for. Besides, never modify a package under the same name as the original. Make a copy under a new name, modify that and use that version.

Comment: @daleif I'd recommend using a different user even if you are the sole user on the system. The main reason not to use root is in case something goes wrong i.e. then it cannot eat the contents of `/usr/bin` or `/etc` or whatever. If you run as yourself, it can delete your entire home directory. For many people, this is probably a greater loss than the system, which can be reinstalled from scratch. I don't see the point in protecting files I could replace with only minor inconvenience, while failing to protect files which I cannot. (Backups are rarely this minute and are for unavoidable stuff.)

Comment: See [my instructions here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/) for details of how to install TeX Live using a dedicated user account.

Comment: @daleif See also [Thérèse's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu#comment597744_187379). This is very common - my editor does it, too - and installing as yourself risks making inadvertent changes unless you (1) never try to compile code which fails with an error, or (2) are always sufficiently alert to avoid further fallout.

Comment: If the main purpose of this question is "only" to modify specific packages in your distribution, you are quite possibly acting against the strong recommendation of the [LPPL](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt), which is usually (but not always) the licence under which the package is licensed. (I'm exaggerating, but) the LPPL generally encourages you to **rename any modified package**. Please [read this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47360/8528). Try this: `mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/ && cp -vi $(kpsewhich <package>.sty ~/temf/tex/latex/my<package>.sty` and then modify mypackage.sty

Comment: @cfr then what about Windows users?

Comment: @daleif I can't help it if people use Windows, surely? I'm not sure which comment you're referring to. Does Windows not have the possibility of a non-admin user who is not you?

Comment: @cfr As far as I know the multiuser tl install on Windows is not locked down by default. An admin has to do that manually. I think I got that working while testing on Windows (not my choice of os either)

Answer (score 11):

`tlmgr` by default installs into the location of the original installation, in your case `/usr/local/texlive/2015`. This is common practice in multi-user environments, and it also is correct that only root or similar admins can change the installation.

There is a special mode for `tlmgr`, called User Mode, that allows installation of some packages into an arbitrary tree, by default `TEXMFHOME` which is `~/texmf`. For this you have to first run `tlmgr init-usertree`, and after that you can install package with `tlmgr --usermode ...`. I recommend reading the relevant section in the documentation, first: https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE

Finally, *if* you can run `sudo` I suggest managing (that is installing, removing etc) the TeX Live installation via `sudo tlmgr`, otherwise you might end up with several copies of the same package, some of them outdated.

Comment: Who can change the installation depends on who installed it with what privileges. I explain [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187379/) how to create and use a dedicated non-privileged user to do this. [I realise that this comment is like telling my grandmother how to suck eggs. It is just a pointer for any non-grandmothers who have yet to learn the knack.]

Comment: @cfr indeed, but in practically all instances if the installation is found in `/usr/local/texlive/` it was root. My reasoning: Someone who manages to install as non-root into `/usr/local/` normally knows what it implies ;-)

Comment: When I use sudo tlmgr the following error appears: sudo: tlmgr: Befehl nicht gefunden (German for command not found).

Comment: @DonMeles because you probably installed for the normal user, and have set up the PATH only for the normal user. But if you do `sudo` all of that is obliterated and root runs with a clean environment, so the PATH does not contain tlmgr.

Answer (score 0):

[Norbert's Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/288639/110064) simplified: (I also needed `-ignore-warning`)

```
tlmgr init-usertree
tlmgr -ignore-warning --usermode install acro datetime2 elsarticle inputenx newunicodechar pdfcomment pstool soulutf8 tablefootnote tabu textpos threeparttable wrapfig
```