# How to change the grad scale values with tkzKiviatDiagram?

Tags: tkz-kiviat

Is it possible to change the tkzKiviatGrad scale that it starts with -2 instead of 0? So the sale in the bellow example would be -2 -1 0 1 2.

Also, can I display the starting point in center of the graph somehow?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=0.8,label distance=1cm,
        gap     = 1.5,  
        lattice = 4]{Barfoo1,Barfoo2,Barfoo3,Barfoo4,Barfoo5,Barfoo6}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue](1,2,3,2,4,0)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=yellow](1,2,4,1,4,2)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=green](1,4,4,2,4,4)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=Aquamarine](1,2,3,1,2,2)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=Magenta](1,3,4,1,4,3)
\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=1](0)
\node[anchor=south west,xshift=-60pt,yshift=40pt] at (current bounding box.south east) 
{
\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{4cm}@{}}
\cellcolor{blue} & Foobar1 \\
\cellcolor{yellow} & Foobar2 \\
\cellcolor{green} & Foobar3\\
\cellcolor{Aquamarine} & Foobar4 \\
\cellcolor{Magenta} & Foobar5 \\
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To solve the problem have a look to [tkz-kiviat.sty](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-kiviat/latex/tkz-kiviat.sty) and the definition of `\tkzKiviatGrad`.*

**Result:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\makeatletter
\def\tkzKiviatGrad{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@KiviatGrad}{\tkz@KiviatGrad[]}} 
\def\tkz@KiviatGrad[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatgrad/.cd,
graduation distance= 0 pt,
prefix ={},
suffix={},
unity=1
 }
 \pgfqkeys{/kiviatgrad}{#1}% 
\let\tikz@label@distance@tmp\tikz@label@distance
\global\let\tikz@label@distance\tkz@kiv@grad
 \foreach \nv in {0,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{ %original: \foreach \nv in {1,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{
 \pgfmathparse{\tkz@kiv@unity*\nv} 
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult-2} %original: \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult}
 \protected@edef\tkz@kiv@gd{\tkz@kiv@prefix$\result$\tkz@kiv@suffix}
    \path[/kiviatgrad/.cd,#1] (0:0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2:\nv*\tkz@kiv@gap) 
       node[label=(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)-90:\tkz@kiv@gd] {}; 
      }
 \let\tikz@label@distance\tikz@label@distance@tmp  
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother

 % \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \makeatletter
% \patchcmd{\tkz@KiviatGrad}{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathresult-2}
%          {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}
%          {\ERRORpatchfailed} 
% \makeatother 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=0.8,label distance=1cm,
        gap     = 1.5,  
        lattice = 4]{Barfoo1,Barfoo2,Barfoo3,Barfoo4,Barfoo5,Barfoo6}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue](1,2,3,2,4,0)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=yellow](1,2,4,1,4,2)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=green](1,4,4,2,4,4)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=Aquamarine](1,2,3,1,2,2)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=Magenta](1,3,4,1,4,3)
\tkzKiviatGrad[unity=1](0)

\node[anchor=south west,xshift=-60pt,yshift=40pt] at (current bounding box.south east) 
{
\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{4cm}@{}}
\cellcolor{blue} & Foobar1 \\
\cellcolor{yellow} & Foobar2 \\
\cellcolor{green} & Foobar3\\
\cellcolor{Aquamarine} & Foobar4 \\
\cellcolor{Magenta} & Foobar5 \\
\end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**1. How to change only the grad scale values?** (solves only problem 1)

You could use `\patchcmd` with `\usepackage{etoolbox}` to redefine a command inside `.sty` file. You have to surround your redefinition with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in order to be able to access or modify commands that contain an @ sign in their names. (Ref.:[@Frank Mittelbach s approach:Modifying .sty files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47360/124842)

For shifting your scale from `0 1 2 3 4` to `-2 -1 0 1 2` you have to subtract `2` ( from computed value of `\pgfmathparse` inside the `\def\tkz@KiviatGrad` definition ) with the redefinition below:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\tkz@KiviatGrad}{\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathresult-2}
         {\typeout{*** SUCCESS ***}}
         {\ERRORpatchfailed}
\makeatother
```

**2. Display the starting point in center** (solves problem 1 and 2)

For the second question i only found the solution to redefine the whole definiton. Because the `for-loop` with variable `\nv` has to start with `0` istead of `1` so add the following to your preamble. To solve also problem 1 the same way replace `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult}` with `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult-2}`. : 
(Ref.:[@Werner s approach :local redefinition with \makeatletter ... \makeatother](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47355/124842)

```
\makeatletter
\def\tkzKiviatGrad{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@KiviatGrad}{\tkz@KiviatGrad[]}} 
\def\tkz@KiviatGrad[#1](#2){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/kiviatgrad/.cd,
graduation distance= 0 pt,
prefix ={},
suffix={},
unity=1
 }
 \pgfqkeys{/kiviatgrad}{#1}% 
\let\tikz@label@distance@tmp\tikz@label@distance
\global\let\tikz@label@distance\tkz@kiv@grad
 \foreach \nv in {0,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{ %original: \foreach \nv in {1,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{
 \pgfmathparse{\tkz@kiv@unity*\nv} 
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult-2} %original: \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{\pgfmathresult}
 \protected@edef\tkz@kiv@gd{\tkz@kiv@prefix$\result$\tkz@kiv@suffix}
    \path[/kiviatgrad/.cd,#1] (0:0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2:\nv*\tkz@kiv@gap) 
       node[label=(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*#2)-90:\tkz@kiv@gd] {}; 
      }
 \let\tikz@label@distance\tikz@label@distance@tmp  
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother
```